# JPQL: cast Long to String to perform LIKE search

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, sql-like, long-integer

I have the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT il
FROM InsiderList il
WHERE ( il.deleteFlag IS NULL OR il.deleteFlag = '0' )
  AND il.clientId = :clientId
  AND (    LOWER( il.name ) LIKE :searchTerm
        OR il.nbr LIKE :searchTerm
        OR LOWER( il.type ) LIKE :searchTerm
        OR LOWER( il.description ) LIKE :searchTerm )
```

The customer wants us to be able to search be the `nbr` field, which is a `java.lang.Long`.

**Q**:

How do you perform a LIKE search on a `java.lang.Long` using JPQL?

Comment: You don't. LIKE is for Strings only, as per the JPQL BNF http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_BNF_Notation

Comment: Is there no way to cast this to string or some other way to call `toString()`?

Comment: have you tried TREAT ?

Comment: You could try with Critieray API and `Expression.as(type)`

Comment: At least for my test database (H2) with Hibernate the following is working:
`SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.id LIKE '%0%'` - please define your JPA provider and database

Comment: DB is Oracle 12 and JPA provider is EclipseLink 2.3.x. Obviously, we're on JPA 2.0, Java EE 6.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `CAST` in HQL:

```
SELECT il
FROM InsiderList il
WHERE ( il.deleteFlag IS NULL OR il.deleteFlag = '0' )
  AND il.clientId = :clientId
  AND (    LOWER( il.name ) LIKE :searchTerm
        OR CAST( il.nbr as string ) LIKE :searchTerm
        OR LOWER( il.type ) LIKE :searchTerm
        OR LOWER( il.description ) LIKE :searchTerm )
```

But you can have serious performance problems doing this, because the database can't use the `nbr` index (if `nbr` column is indexed).

Comment: Too bad the question was clearly about JPQL not HQL... we're using various JPA providers...

Comment: My mistake, @Kawu. Native query is an option for you? Do you think about create a new column with the `nbr` as VARCHAR type?

Comment: so Dherik, while using JPQL is native query the only option as there seems to be no `CAST` or `CONVERT` in JPQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `CAST(num as string)` or `CONCAT(num,'')`. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

simple.. `CAST( field as text/varchar) LIKE`
It must be a type knows by the database (not **string** like in HQL)

And looking at your query there is a more efficient way to do it:

With **CONCAT** you don't have to cast NON String arguments (WHEN there is more than one and AT LEAST one is an String)

This works: LOWER(CONCAT(name, **nbr**, description)) LIKE

This doesn't: CONCAT(nbr), I guess because it doesn't recognize a JPQL function CONCAT(Long.. )

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the same issue by creating a @transient field in the entity and then used below query for search :

```
id LIKE CONCAT('%',:txnId)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you consider trying with the JPQL `TRIM(num)` ?